# How to keep ChildProcess from running out of memory? Electron/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron

Using Electron and Node.js to write a simple user interface to a process that generates data, and then allows the user to call gnuplot to show the data. Here is the code in main.js that calls gnuplot (gnuplot5-qt).

```
var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
  {
      label: 'Run Graph',
      click() {
        commandLine()
      }
  },
// Other code
function commandLine () {
    var child = require('child_process').execFile;
    var executablePath = "/usr/bin/gnuplot";
    var parameters = ["-p","-e","filename='/home/prog1/PP_Logs/log1.txt'","/home/prog1/plot_log.p"];

    child(executablePath, parameters, function(err, data) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(data.toString());
    });
```

gnuplot always opens, sometimes it stays open and I can exit it normally, but randomly it will close immediately after opening and prints the following error:

```
{ Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/gnuplot -p -e filename='/home/prog1/PP_Logs/log1.txt' /home/prog1/plot_log.p

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:921:16)
at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:348:11)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:549:12)
killed: false,
code: null,
signal: 'SIGSEGV',
cmd: '/usr/bin/gnuplot -p -e filename=\'/home/prog1/PP_Logs/log1.txt\' /home/prog1/plot_log.p' }
```

This same code works without issue if gimp is launched instead of gnuplot:

```
 var executablePath = "/usr/bin/gimp";
 var parameters = ["-s","/home/geenweb/Pictures/lgcm110.jpg"];
```

Given the SIGSEGV, I'm assuming that gnuplot is running out of memory when it crashes. Is there some way to allocate more memory? Is there a better way to call gnuplot? I'm just learning Electron, Node.js, and javascript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: SIGSEGV does not mean out of memory. SIGSEGV means Invalid memory reference. Some thing bad is happening with gnuplot. Does it work on command line with the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should make sure you're running the current LTS version of Node, which at the time of this writing is v8.9.4.

If, as you note, you are working with Electron which provides its own NodeJS runtime, you should still keep both Electron and your local version of NodeJS as up-to-date as possible.

[`ChildProcess.execFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) runs your command in a new process by default which might be the cause of your error. You may wish to specify that your command be run in a newly spawned shell by setting the `shell` flag in the options you pass to `execFile()` to either `true` which will cause the default `/bin/sh` shell to be used or to a path to the shell you wish to use.

Running your process in a `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` shell will give you access to the shell `ulimit` built-in command which will provide you a means to modify resource limits for the shell. See [Setting Limits With ulimit](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693414/operating-systems/setting-limits-with-ulimit.html) for information about the `ulimit` command and how to use it.

If this is the case, you'll need to wrap your command invocation in a shell-script that first runs `ulimit` with the correct limits.

See [Limit Memory Usage For A Single Linux Process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process) for further discussion on this topic.

Your problem might also be caused by the default allocated size of the buffers used to transfer the running command's output via `stdout` and `stderr`.

If this is the case and the program's output exceeds `200*1024` bytes, you can use the `maxBuffer` in the options you pass to `execFile()` to increase the size of these buffers.

Comment: The tag states @greenweb is using electron. You can only use the nodejs version shipped with electron. This is  v8.2.1 at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct of course. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I am using Node v8.9.4.

I thought gnuplot was work fine when launched from the shell, but I tried launching repeatedly after reading your replies. Sure enough, I was also getting a segmentation violation there every so many runs. I googled and found this:   [https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1885/](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1885/)  I changed the terminal in my script file from wxt to qt and now I no longer have the crash either from command line, or launching it via electron. Thanks for giving me the hints I needed to look in the right place.

Comment: Are you sure you are using node 8.9.4? Even if you have  installed this version, electron is using its own, as far as I know. You can check your versions via `console.log (process.versions)` . I'm just curious.

Comment: Ah, interesting. If I check node version at the terminal "node --version" it says "v8.9.4". But if I check via console.log (process.versions) it returns "node 8.2.1"

Comment: Yeah, that will become an issue when you use npm modules which needs compiling. You will see some error messages like `compiled against a different node.js` and a hint with NODE_MODULE_VERSION.  Best to keep both node versions in sync. You can use for instance nvm.